# I am trying to get the data from the textbox and seach in my database and show the result below the textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```html
<!----- 
getCedula.php 
Here I get the data from the script and start the search and send the result
---------------------------- - -->
<?php
require("conexion.php");

$cedula=$_REQUEST["cedula"];
//$cedula="0922615646";
echo $cedula;
$query="SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cedula=".$cedula."";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
    echo ''.$fila["cedula"].' '.$fila["nombres"].'';
}
// Liberar resultados
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Cerrar la conexión
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

```js
function gocedula(Text){  

                        var form_data = {
                                is_ajax: 1,
                                cedula: val(Text)
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "getCedula.php",
                                data: form_data,
                                success: function(response)
                                {
                                    $('.actualizar-formulario').html(response).fadeIn();
                                }
                        });


             
}
            </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--
In the textbox with the id coger-cedula I put the numbers that i want to search and send them to getCedula.php
Somehow it does nothing
-->
<form>
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cédula</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input id="coger-cedula" type="text" class="form-control rounded" name="cedula" placeholder="Cédula" maxlength="10"
onchange="gocedula($(this).val());" onkeyup="gocedula($(this).val());" onpaste="gocedula($(this).val());" oninput="gocedula($(this).val());">
</div>
</div>
<div class="actualizar-formulario">
</div>
</form>
```

The javascript doesn't get the data from the textbox. If I put and alert I can see that the data goes through the function, but it doesn't send into the ajax "form_data". I tryed to addapt it, because it works in a form with select tag.
It is supose that everytime that someone types something in the textbox, the javascript function has to send it to "getCedula.php" and look it in the database, so if it finds something it will show the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in js a code! Why do you use val(Text)??? 
There is no such function in JavaScript.
Maybe you have mixed with $ ('.class_name') .val ()???
There is a working option.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Ansver!</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Form</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input id="coger-cedula" type="text" class="form-control rounded" name="cedula" placeholder="text" maxlength="10" onchange="gocedula($(this).val());" onkeyup="gocedula($(this).val());" onpaste="gocedula($(this).val());" oninput="gocedula($(this).val());">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actualizar-formulario">
  </div>
 </form>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     function gocedula(text) { 
   var form_data = {
    is_ajax: 1,
    cedula: text
   };

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax.php",
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response) {
     $('.actualizar-formulario').html(response).fadeIn();
    }
   });
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
$cedula=$_REQUEST["cedula"];
echo $cedula;
?>
```

Comment: Super my friend